# Proving an inequality that looks related to the Binomial series,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Edit:  I changed the inequality to the one that I think was meant to be asked.  This is a former exam question from my math dept, and it is relatively old - from 1993.  So, I think there was a typo on the R.H.S. of the inequality.  Thanks,

I am trying to prove that, for $x>0$

$$\big(1 + \frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{8}x^2\big) < \sqrt{1+x} < \big(1+ \frac{1}{2}x\big)$$

It's easy to notice that the left term is just the Taylor expansion of the middle term, using the generalized Binomial series.

I don't know how to achieve the inequality, so I expanded out to a few more terms to see whether I can say something more:

$$\sqrt{1+x}= \big(1 + \frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{8}x^2 +\frac{1}{16}x^3-\frac{5}{128}x^4 + ... \big)$$

So now it's more obvious that $\sqrt{1+x}$ has an alternating Taylor series, valid for $|x|<1$.  Also, the coefficients are monotone decreasing to zero, in absolute value.

Where can I go from here?

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: There is at least one error in your inequalities. How can $\sqrt{1+x}$ be bounded above by $3/2$? Please clarify.

Comment: I think he meant $1+{1\over2}x$.

Comment: Hi @gammatester, perhaps the right hand term is $(1+\frac{1}{2} x)$.

Comment: I think so too @cr001 -- but as I read it here on paper, it is 1/2.  But also, this is a 1993 exam question, so there's definitely a possibility of transcription error.

Comment: I have edited my question @gammatester to ask the question that I think was meant to be asked.  Also, I notice now that if I just couple off terms in the expansion... (-1/8 + 1/16) + (-5/128 +  ..) + ... these terms are always net-negative, because of the alternating nature and the fact that the numbers, in absolute value, are monotone decreasing.  Perhaps I can work from here now...

Comment: The right inequality is Bernoulli's IE, it is strict because because $x>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x>0$ we have that $\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)^2 = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{4} > 1+x$, hence $1+\frac{x}{2}>\sqrt{1+x}$.

On the other hand,
$$1+\frac{x}{2}-\sqrt{1+x} = \frac{\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)^2-(1+x)}{1+\frac{x}{2}+\sqrt{1+x}}<\frac{\frac{x^2}{4}}{2}$$
gives the other side of the wanted inequality.

Comment: Thanks for such a pretty solution @JackD'Aurizio.  I had expected a nasty Taylor estimate, so this is a nice surprise.  Have a great night :-)